# getting empty set for a particular xpath

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

```
<span id="hs18Price" title="Price of Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 G7102 Android Mobile Phone -Black" itemprop="price">           
<span class="WebRupee">₹</span>
22499
</span>
```

I want to get 22499.Can anyone suggest the xpath query to get 22499?

```
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)  
price = tree.xpath("//span[@id='hs18Price']/text()")
```

Above is the python code ,if i print price its showing empty list.

Comment: That query should return two text nodes, one only containing whitespace (before the currency symbol span) and one with the number in it. Are you only looking at the first text node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `//span[@id="hs18Price"]/text()` against your sample xml and it returns `22499`

You can try it here against this tester tool
http://www.unit-testing.net/Xpath

I would also double check that the html is present on the page at the time the xpath runs. Is it loaded through ajax?